# sqlfluff command not found

Tags: pip, zsh, sqlfluff

I did install `sqlfluff` on my mac with M1 chip using the command;
`pip3 install sqlfluff==0.7.0`. It went through the installation process as expected and I was able to locate `.sqlfluff` config file at proper location. But when I run the command `sqlfluff --verison` I am getting following error.

`zsh: command not found: sqlfluff`

Can I kindly get some help to debug it? thanx

[image]

Comment: `echo $PATH` ? `pip3 show --files sqlfluff` ?

Comment: _to debug_  : Track down where you are changing `PATH`, respectively `path`.  Find out why the directory needed here is not in the _path_.

Comment: @phd thanx for your suggestions. I did run the commands as you advised. plz see attached screenshot in my original question. Does it mean that I have it installed but I can't access it.

Comment: @jay IWB better to have it in text for easier copy/pasting. Well, you need to add `…/Python/3.8/bin` to `PATH`

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem,  did you solve it?

Comment: @phd How can I understand what should I have to add in PATH?

Comment: Did you install into an env? If so, is the env active when you try to run the command?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an Intel MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey 12.5. After installing `sqlfluff` with the `pip3 install sqlfluff` command, I received the following error message:

```
$ sqlfluff
-bash: sqlfluff: command not found
```

Solved the problem installing it with `brew`:

```
$ brew install sqlfluff
```

Then,

```
$ sqlfluff --version
sqlfluff, version 1.2.1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but:

You can install sqlfluff as root

```bash
sudo pip install sqlfluff
```

This way it will be available under `/usr/local/bin` which is part of `$PATH`

If you install it as your user (non-root)

```bash
pip install sqlfluff
```

The executable will be available under `~/.local/bin/` which usually is not part of `$PATH`

In this case you can either add `~/.local/bin/` to `$PATH` or copy `sqlfluff` into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`